# Flag Records From A Filtered Form

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have my Form set to filter to make sure that only clients who need to be mailed are loaded into this form.

> [Complete]=No And [Call 1]="Wrong Number" Or [Complete]=No And [Call 2]="Wrong Number" Or [Complete]=No And [Call 3]="No Answer" or [Complete]=No And [Call 3]="Unavailable" or [Complete]=No And [Call 3]="Wrong Number"

I then have a mail merge done to print there letters and envelopes out. I have a field "Complete" set as a `Yes/No` defaulted to `No`. I would like to have a button that will flag all of these records filtered into this form to `Yes` for completed so after they do the mail merge we won't do them again.

My question is how do I flag only these records without doing the entire table?

Thanks in advance for any help in this matter.

Comment: The code is simply the Filter on load in access that I have set now to show why I need to flag the complete field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an open form has an active filter the `.RecordsetClone` for that form returns the filtered recordset. So, your button to update the [Completed] flag could simply do something like this:

```
Private Sub btnUpdateCompleted_Click()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
If Not (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        rst.Edit
        rst!Completed = True
        rst.Update
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```